# In apartments or hotels why do we add a 0 between the floor number and room/apartment number?

Tags: user-behavior, user-perception

Like a room on 4th will be named as 401 to 408. Why don't we use 4-1, 4-2 till 4-8?

Answer (score 1):

### Why not?

From a natural language perspective, it's easier to say "four oh one" than "four dash one" and "four one" sounds like two separate numbers.

Since most buildings will have less than 100 rooms to a floor, you don't need the added flexibility. and once you get past single digits, you'll be using more space: `421` vs `4-21`.

And dashes just aren't that graceful. When an architect is envisioning the interior design, `401` probably just seems more visually pleasing than `4-1`.

Most importantly, I'm sure it just convention stemming from some historical precedent long ago.

Even if you were in the mood to change things up, I can't think of any real-world gain to using the dash as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

There are also hotels with room 41 or 42.

The reason is usually because there might be 10 or more rooms per floor. Thus 2 digits are needed for the room number (from 01 to nn where nn is the number of rooms per floor) and one (or more) for the floor.

Room 13 would be at the bottom floor. Room 1120 is the 20th room of the 11th floor.